# Rendering 3D .step files with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, 3d, step

I'm looking for a way to render 3D models in JavaScript (React), specifically .step files made to ISO industrial standard witch are universal across cad platforms?

If someone knows the good library or solution to this problem please refer me to it.
Thanks in advance.